# Autocomplete Geocoding in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

How can I access **Google's Autocomplete Geocoding Service** in **Android** not in JavaScript (just like we can see in Google Map version of Android by clicking on direction menu we can see two textbox and those are Geocoding Autocomplete service).

Is there any API exposed for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented using Android's [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) and [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)